# Android Studio Hidpi

Tags: 16.04, kde, android-studio, scale-mode, hdpi

Is there any way to scale Android Studio UI on hidpi screen? It looks tiny and unusable.
Desktop and other applications look ok (changed display scale and dpi in system settings), but Android Studio is still too small.
3840x2160 15.6", KDE 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see here how to tell the IDE to scale for a hidpi display:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/high-density-display-with-android-studio

However, I found this to work most of the times but not always. What always works is to run the following command in the terminal before launching Android Studio:

```
xrandr --dpi 192
```